# Mirror modifier not working for some reason

Tags: modeling

I used other ones with the same question but they're not solving my issue. The mirror modifier isn't working, and I've done as much as I can.[image]

Comment: Right-click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor or go into Edit mode and move your object there.

Comment: By default the Mirror modifier will use the object origin as mirror axis, for the moment the mirrored mesh is overlapping the original mesh, you need to either move the origin as John suggest, or create an object that will be the Mirror Object

Answer (score 2):

By default the *Mirror* modifier will use the object origin as mirror axis, for the moment the mirrored mesh is overlapping the original mesh, see:

[image]

You need to either move the origin as John suggests (or move the mesh away from it origin)...

[image]

Or create an object that will be the *Mirror Object*:

[image]